# Difference in date value in localhost

Tags: php, mysql, date

In my localhost WAMP stack, I am having a database table which has a column "Birth-date" as a "date-time" column type.

I am running the below SQL for that table to get the birth-date of the current year and its unix timestamp value. No issues here.

```
SELECT dateValue,

DATE_ADD(dateValue, INTERVAL YEAR(CURDATE())-YEAR(dateValue) YEAR) "Date1",

UNIX_TIMESTAMP(
   DATE_ADD(dateValue, INTERVAL YEAR(CURDATE())-YEAR(dateValue) YEAR)
) "Date2"

FROM base_date
```

For example I get the below output from the SQL.

```
DATEVALUE                       DATE1                           DATE2
-------------------------------+-------------------------------+-----------------
December, 18 1980 00:00:00+0000 December, 18 2013 00:00:00+0000 1387305000
December, 20 1985 00:00:00+0000 December, 20 2013 00:00:00+0000 1387477800
```

The problem is that when I try to display that unix formatted timestamp value in PHP, the date is not shown correct. There is a change of 1 day.

```
echo gmdate("Y-m-d", "1387305000");  // Displays 2013-12-17 and not 2013-12-18
echo gmdate("Y-m-d", "1387477800");  // Displays 2013-12-19 and not 2013-12-20
```

The confusing part is that :

**When I test this with SQL Fiddle values, it worked correct.** The unix timestamp out of the SQL is different for the same date in my localhost mysql(5.5.24) and the version available in sqlfiddle.com(5.5.32).

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/25e032/3/0

What could be the difference? Is it related to timezone or sql version or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My host has the timezone set on MySQL to their local timezone (Pacific Time), so a PHP time() value (GMT) put into the database and displayed as a MySQL time is off by 8 hours or so. So, it may be a matter of your host's MySQL configuration. Be careful about mixing PHP timestamps and MySQL timestamps.

Comment: Any idea where to check that timezone for MYSQL?

Comment: I have no idea... possibly in my.cnf? First, I would get a timestamp from PHP time() and insert it into a TIMESTAMP field, and then read back the formatted date and time. That should give you an idea of what timezone the MySQL server is operating in. If your host permits you to override the default timezone (my.cnf? you'd have to read the MySQL docs), you might be able to, but you'll probably have to ask them what's up.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `gmdate()` which adjusts to GM timezone. What is the default timezone set for your PHP? Try changing `gmdate()` to `date()` and see if it works correctly.

`date_default_timezone_get()` -> http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-get.php

On the `gmdate()` documentation you can get an explanation, look at Example 1:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gmdate.php

Comment: As in my question, the MYSQL function returns different values for same date. So that's where the actual problem starts even before using the PHP function.